# Spark fails to convert String to TIMESTAMP

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, time, hive

I have a hive table that contains a String column: this is an example:

```
| DT                            |                                                       
|-------------------------------|
| 2019-05-07 00:03:53.837000000 |
```

when I try to import the table inside a Spark-Scala DF transforming the String to a timestamp I only have null values:

```
val df = spark.sql(s"""select to_timestamp(dt_maj, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') from ${use_database}.pz_send_demande_diffusion""").show()


| DT   |                                                       
|------|
| null |
```

Doing

```
val df = spark.sql(s"""select dt from ${use_database}.pz_send_demande_diffusion""").show()
```

gives a good result (column with the String values). So Spark is importing te column normally.

I also tried:

```
val df = spark.sql(s"""select to_timestamp('2005-05-04 11:12:54.297', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') from ${use_database}.pz_send_demande_diffusion""").show()
```

And it worked! It returns a TIMESTAMPs column.

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim your extra 0s. Then,

```
df.withColumn("new", to_timestamp($"date".substr(lit(1),length($"date") - 6), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).show(false)
```

the result is:

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------+
|date                         |new                |
+-----------------------------+-------------------+
|2019-05-07 00:03:53.837000000|2019-05-07 00:03:53|
+-----------------------------+-------------------+
```

The schema:

```
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- new: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use following format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS` for this type of data `2019-05-07 00:03:53.837000000`

Comment: Thank you. I already tried that. still returns Null. for the column

Comment: Maybe because Spark timestamp type is in seconds and you have higher precision. Just try to trim trim string or change format to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` before applying to_timestamp